# Login vs Register in PythonSocialAuth

Tags: django, authentication, python-social-auth

I'm using [PythonSocialAuth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) (v0.1.23) and I need to differentiate "Register" (create a new user account) from Login. In the [PSA Django example](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/examples/django_example), if a new user tries to login, the pipeline logic redirects the new user to a "register form"; I want to avoid this "Login or Register" behavior.

What I need is:

1. Raise an error if a **new** user tries to Login.
2. Force new users to Register in order to create the a new account/profile.

Any idea how can I manipulate the PSA pipeline in order to accomplish this?
(I'm using Django 1.6).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you let new users use Login method without throwing an error and at the end of pipeline check if user has been loggedin or created and based on that condition redirect him to register form or main page of your app?

Comment: @daniula The problem is: The pipeline for both Login and Register starts in the same way, I don't know how to differentiate the Login path from the Register one.

Comment: The pipelines get a flag ``is_new`` just to identify that, if you add a pipeline before ``create_user``, you can identify a new user registering to the site and can stop the process right there if you want. If you put your function after ``create_user``, then you can do the same, but the user instance will be already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments and suggestions. I realized how to resolve my problem, and this is my solution, hope it helps to others.

The first problem is that PSA uses the same pipeline for both:

1. registering new users and
2. login existing ones.

So, it's mandatory differentiate one pipeline flow form the other. This can be done (have to be done?) arranging the query string:

1. `<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?register=1">`, for Sign up.
2. `<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">`, for regular Login.

The second problem is how to read the `register` parameter in the PSA pipeline. This task have to be done setting `FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION` (see the [PSA docs](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#pass-custom-get-post-parameters-and-retrieve-them-on-authentication)):

```
# settings.py
...
FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['register']
```

Finally, my pipeline looks like this:

```
# settings.py
...
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'my.path.custom_pipeline.clean_pipeline',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'my.path.custom_pipeline.redirect_to_join_form',
    ... 
)
```

And my custom tasks:

```
# custom_pipeline.py

from social.pipeline.partial import partial
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def clean_pipeline(strategy, *args, **kwargs):
        _register = strategy.session.get('register', None)
        strategy.session.flush()
        strategy.session['register'] = _register

@partial
def redirect_to_join_form(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if user and user.username:
        return
    if is_new and strategy.session_get('register', False) == '1':
        strategy.session.pop('register')
        return redirect('users_join_form')
    if is_new and strategy.session_get('saved_username'):
        return {'username': strategy.session_get('saved_username')}
    messages.add_message(
        strategy.request, messages.ERROR,
        "Error. Account not registered %s (%s), " % 
        (strategy.backend.name.capitalize(), details['username'])
    )
    return redirect('users_login')
```

That's all. Hope it helps.